# !$ in bash script

Tags: bash, scripting

Saw the use of `!$` on this site, so I made a short bash script "`bang_dollar.sh`" as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e '\n'
  
touch touche.txt
vi !$
```

This was a copy verbatim of what someone posted as a solution on this site (to a different question).

I ran

```
$ touch touche.txt                           
$ vi !$
```

from the command line, and vi does in fact open `touche.txt` for editing.

My bang_dollar.sh script however, creates a file named  "touche.txt", and vi opens,
but "`!$`" is literally interpreted as `!$`, so vi opens a file for editing named "`!$`".

Is it possible to use "`!$`" in a bash script with some sort of masking?  And shouldn't a file named "`!$`" be illegal on BASH 5.1.4?

Comment: "shouldn't a file named "!$" be illegal" - No. (Or well, if you asked me, it _should_, not just in the shell but in the OS. But it isn't.)

Comment: In a script, I'd rather use a variable than rely on history expansion, `file=touche.txt; vi "$file"`. But you do you.